# how to install linux phat client to connect vpn server from ubuntu machine?

Tags: 16.04, networking, server, vpn

I am unable to install this phat client. Please someone guide me to install phat client in ubuntu 16.04

```
sudo ./install_linux_phat_client.sh
```

output:

```
Checking for NSS Libs: NSS library is not available .. exiting
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first move is to inspect `install_linux_phat_client.sh` and see how it's deciding to issue that error message.

However, on MY Ubuntu 16.04.5 YMMV:

```
walt@bat:~(0)$ dpkg -l libnss*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                    Version                  Architecture             Description
+++-=======================================-========================-========================-====================================================================================
un  libnss-db                               <none>                   <none>                   (no description available)
ii  libnss-mdns:amd64                       0.10-7                   amd64                    NSS module for Multicast DNS name resolution
ii  libnss3:amd64                           2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04. amd64                    Network Security Service libraries
ii  libnss3-1d:amd64                        2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04. amd64                    Network Security Service libraries - transitional package
ii  libnss3-nssdb                           2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04. all                      Network Security Security libraries - shared databases
walt@bat:~(0)$ apt-cache search libnss
libnss-db - NSS module for using Berkeley Databases as a naming service
libnss-extrausers - nss module to have an additional passwd, shadow and group file
libnss-mdns - NSS module for Multicast DNS name resolution
libnss-myhostname - nss module providing fallback resolution for the current hostname
libnss-sss - Nss library for the System Security Services Daemon
libnss3 - Network Security Service libraries
libnss3-1d - Network Security Service libraries - transitional package
libnss3-dbg - Debugging symbols for the Network Security Service libraries
libnss3-dev - Development files for the Network Security Service libraries
libnss3-nssdb - Network Security Security libraries - shared databases
winbind - service to resolve user and group information from Windows NT servers
libnss-cache - NSS module for using nsscache-generated files
libnss-docker - nss module for finding Docker containers
libnss-gw-name - nss module that names the current gateway’s IP address
libnss-ldap - NSS module for using LDAP as a naming service
libnss-ldapd - NSS module for using LDAP as a naming service
libnss-lwres - NSS module for using bind9's lwres as a naming service
libnss-mymachines - nss module to resolve hostnames for local container instances
libnss-mysql-bg - NSS module for using MySQL as a naming service
libnss-pgsql2 - NSS module for using PostgreSQL as a naming service
libnss-rainbow2 - nss library for rainbow
libnss-resolve - nss module to resolve names via systemd-resolved
libnss-rsbac2 - RSBAC NSS module
libnss-securepass - NSS (Name Service Switch) module for Securepass
libnss-winbind - Samba nameservice integration plugins
libnss-wrapper - NSS wrapper library
libnss3-tools - Network Security Service tools
libpam-ccreds - Pam module to cache authentication credentials
libpam-ldap - Pluggable Authentication Module for LDAP
nslcd - daemon for NSS and PAM lookups using LDAP
nss-passwords - read passwords from a Mozilla keyring
nss-updatedb - Cache name service directories in DB format
nsscache - asynchronously synchronise local NSS databases with remote directory services
pynslcd - daemon for NSS and PAM lookups via LDAP - Python version
python-libsss-nss-idmap - Python bindings for the SID lookups library
python3-libsss-nss-idmap - Python3 bindings for the SID lookups library
```

I suggest that you install the `libnss3` package.

Answer (score 0):

@gopi-nathan
After checking the file I found that it tries to:

```
if [ -a $FIREFOX_DEB_ARCH -o -a $FIREFOX_RHEL_ARCH ] ; then
    echo "NSS libs available"
else
    echo "NSS library is not available .. exiting"
    exit 1
fi
```

Where:

```
FIREFOX_DEB_ARCH=/usr/lib/firefox/firefox
FIREFOX_RHEL_ARCH=/usr/lib64/firefox/firefox
```

That said, you can do:
`sudo apt install firefox`

Answer (score 0):

You must use terminal to unpack installer and run it:

```
tar -zxf linux_phat_client.tgz
cd linux_phat_client
sudo ./install_linux_phat_client.sh
```

and use to run without sudo:

```
./gui/naclient.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

The script cannot found firefox. If you already have it just find it and change firefox path in the script.
$ whereis firefox
firefox: /usr/bin/firefox /usr/local/bin/firefox
$ ls -l /usr/bin/firefox
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Jun 28 07:15 /usr/bin/firefox -> /opt/firefox/firefox

Edit line 60 to correct firefox path.
60 # FIREFOX_DEB_ARCH=/usr/lib/firefox/firefox
61 FIREFOX_DEB_ARCH=/opt/firefox/firefox
62 FIREFOX_RHEL_ARCH=/usr/lib64/firefox/firefox

Then run installation script again.
$ sudo ./install_linux_phat_client.sh

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using snap firefox package, you'll have issues with installing the VPN client.

The workaround is to find the firefox folder and to link it in as the installed looking it for

```
FIREFOX_DEB_ARCH=/usr/lib/firefox/firefox
FIREFOX_RHEL_ARCH=/usr/lib64/firefox/firefox
```

After installing firefox (`sudo apt install firefox`)

Find the root dir of the firefox and to link it as `/usr/lib/firefox`

In my case it was

```
ln -s /snap/firefox/current/usr/lib/firefox /usr/lib/firefox
```